# How to batch cp files and rename by adding prefix in current directory in one command-line without using for loop?

Tags: shell, command-line, cp

Example:

```
.
├── f1.md
├── f2.md
├── f3.md
├── f4.txt
├── f5.csv
├── f6.doc
├── s1
├── s2
├── s3
└── s4

4 directories, 6 files
```

I want to copy  `f1.md/f2.md/f3.md` in current directory, and the results would be `t-f1.md/t-f2.md/t-f3.md`.(prefix is `t-`)

Trying and Hope:

`for file in *md;do cp -a $file t-$file;done` will get result but it seems very long by using `for` loop. I hope if there is shorter and simple command to get the same results.

Comment: a bit shorter but still using loop `for file in *md;do cp -a {,t-}$file ;done`

Comment: @αғsнιη Hi, could you explain `{,t-}$file` is the same as `t-$file`?

Comment: that's just a [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) and expands to `$file t-$file`.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way with GNU **`parallel`**:

```
parallel --no-notice 'cp "{}" "t-{}"' ::: *.md
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

To copy the files the loop you already have is the shortest way to do it. If you want to do it without the loop you could combine `cp` `rename` and `mv`

```
mkdir tmp
cp -a *.md tmp
(cd tmp && rename '' 't-' tmp/*.md)
mv temp/*.md .
```

This reduces the commands you have to run (only one cp command vs one for each file), this may or may not make the program faster to run - you would need to benchmark it. But will fail if you have a very large number of files as we pass all of the files to the `cp` `rename` and `mv`.

Answer (score 0):

With `mmv` / `mcp`:

```
mcp '*.md' t-#1.md
```

Ex. given

```
$ tree .
.
├── f1.md
├── f2.md
├── f3.md
├── f4.txt
├── f5.csv
├── f6.doc
├── s1
├── s2
├── s3
└── s4

0 directories, 10 files
```

Then

```
$ mcp -v '*.md' t-#1.md
f1.md -> t-f1.md : done
f2.md -> t-f2.md : done
f3.md -> t-f3.md : done
```

resulting in

```
$ tree .
.
├── f1.md
├── f2.md
├── f3.md
├── f4.txt
├── f5.csv
├── f6.doc
├── s1
├── s2
├── s3
├── s4
├── t-f1.md
├── t-f2.md
└── t-f3.md

0 directories, 13 files
```